# ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-175) UT005023: Exception handling request to /App/Loginaction: java.lang. NullPointerException

Tags: linux, jboss, war

I am encountering an error after successfully deploying my .war file and accessing the web page. The page loads successfully, but upon entering my username and password, I receive an error. Can anyone please assist me with resolving this issue?

Comment: Which error? What software versions are you using?

Comment: I am using it on jboss 7.3

Comment: A stack trace would be useful. You're not providing much to go on here.